Imputing a categorical variable with constraint in MICE package in R
I would like to ask for help and advice.
I have a dataset where one nominal variable has 4 values, all have some presence in the dataset. Some data were lost, but it is known that the missing values can be two of the four categories.
I saw that some people recommend removing all other cathegories, but I don't think it's the right way, please, correct me if I am wrong:
Imputing a categorical variable with MICE but restricting the possible values
While trying to add constraints, I came across the discussion where Prof. Stef van Buuren recommended squeeze_vec() function here: https://github.com/amices/mice/discussions/507
I tried the squeeze_vec() function and it didn't work with factor variables.
I tried to implement the following function then:
Here is the code:
# Load libraries
library(readr)
library(mice)
library(dplyr)
library(careless)
library(readxl)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(base)
#Set directory
input.data.path <- paste0(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path), "/")
setwd(input.data.path)

#Loading the data
df = read_excel(path = '4unies_quantitative_no_sds_clean_noid.xlsx')

Convert columns to factors using base R
cols<-c("gender","language","education","marital","exchProg","cctrain", "School") # Creates a vector of column names
df[cols]<-lapply(df[cols],as.factor)


set.seed(1234)

imp<-mice(df,maxit = 0,print=F) # a dry run.

predM<-imp$predictorMatrix # in the predictor matrix: columns are predictors, rows are predicted vars.
#predM[c("","",""),]<-0 # these vars aren't predicted
predM[,c("exchProgDue", "sf23", "sf24", "sf25", "sf26",
"sf27","sf28","sf29","sf30","sf31")]<-0 # these vars aren't used as predictors for any vars.

predM

Setting a method for predicting each variable.
meth<-imp$method

meth[c("as1","as2","as3",
"cca1","cca2","cca3",
"sf1","sf2","sf3","sf4","sf5","sf6","sf7","sf8","sf9","sf10",
"sf11","sf12","sf13","sf14","sf15","sf16","sf17","sf18","sf19","sf20",
"sf21","sf22","sf23","sf24","sf25","sf26","sf27","sf28","sf29","sf30",
"sf31","sf32","sf33","sf34","sf35","sf36",
"soc1","soc2","soc3","soc4","soc5","soc6","soc7","soc8","soc9","soc10",
"soc11","soc12","soc13",
"es1","es2","es3","es4","es5","es6","es7","es8","es9","es10",
"ccm1","ccm2","ccm3","ccm4","ccm5",
"a1","a2","a3","a4",
"pss1","pss2", "pss3", "pss4","pss5","pss6", "pss7", "pss8", "pss9", "pss10",
"age")] <- "pmm"
meth[c("gender","ses","language","education","marital",
"exchProg","exchProgDue","cctrain","cctraindue")]<-""

#Possible values are 1,2,3,4
#I want to impute 1 and 2.
mice.impute.School <- function(y, ry, x, ...) {
selected_obs <- !ry | (y %in% c("1", "2"))
y_miss <- mice.impute.polyreg(
forcats::fct_drop(y[selected_obs]),
ry[selected_obs],
x[selected_obs, ], ...
)
return(y_miss)
}

meth["School"] <- "School"

imp_2 <- mice(
df, pred=predM, meth = meth, maxit = 1, m = 5, printFlag = TRUE, ridge=0.01
)

imp_n1<-complete(imp_2,1)
table(df$School, useNA="always")
table(imp_n1$School, useNA="always")

map(1:5, (x) complete(imp_2, x)) %>%
map((d) d$School[is.na(df$School)]) %>%
unlist() %>% table(useNA = "ifany")
####


#The results are a bit disappointing:

#Initial data
> table(df$School, useNA="always")

   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
  10   28  205  193  105 

#One imputation with that function in the methods and there are NAs
imp_2 <- mice(
df, pred=predM, meth = meth, maxit = 1, m = 5, printFlag = TRUE, ridge=0.01
)

table(imp_n1$School, useNA="always")


   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
  27   51  234  227    2

#Using map function reduced the number in category 3 and 4 and there are NAs

map(1:5, (x) complete(imp_2, x)) %>%

map((d) d$School[is.na(df$School)]) %>%
unlist() %>% table(useNA = "ifany")

   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
 129  126  134  126   10



